# Javascript push not outputing the right value

Tags: javascript, arrays, push

I want to push this value to router.PORTS[i].packetdata
but it's not giving me the exact value.. the push function also loops
and give me the wrong value..
The wrong code is on line 72.

but when I tried
router.PORTS[i].packetdata = message;
on line 72.
the value is right but it's not pushing to the array.

```
            function Router(PORTS){
                rex = this;
            }

            Router.prototype = {
                "PORTS": [],
                connect: function(devicename,PORT){
                    devicename.PORT = PORT;
                    this.PORTS.push(devicename);

                },
                totalPackets: function(PORT){
                    if(PORT){
                        for (var i=0;i<rex.PORTS.length;i++)
                        {
                            if(rex.PORTS[i].PORT == PORT){
                                console.log('total packets by PORT', rex.PORTS[i])
                            }
                        }
                    }else{
                        return rex.packetdata.length;
                    }

                },
                totalBytes: function(){
                    totalBytes = [];
                    result = 0;
                    for (var i=0;i<rex.packetdata.length;i++)
                    { 
                        totalBytes.push(rex.packetdata[i].message.length)
                    }

                    for (var i = 0; i< totalBytes.length; i++) {
                    result += totalBytes[i];
                    }
                    return result;

                },
                packetdata: []
            }

            function Device(ip){
                this.ip = ip;

            }

            Device.prototype = {
                DeviceName: "",
                IP: this.ip,
                PORT: "",
                data:[],
                incomingBuffer: "",
                totalPackets:"",
                totalBytes:"",
                emit: function(data,packets){
                    rex.packetdata.push(packets);
                },
                packetdata: []
            }


            function Packet(ip,message) {
              this.ip = ip;
              this.message = message;
              for (var i=0;i<rex.PORTS.length;i++)
                { 
                    if(router.PORTS[i]['ip'] == ip){

                        router.PORTS[i].incomingBuffer = router.PORTS[i].incomingBuffer + this.message; 
                        // I want to push this value to router.PORTS[i].packetdata
                        // my code router.PORTS[i].packetdata.push(message);
                        router.PORTS[i].packetdata = message;
                        console.log(ip, router.PORTS[i].ip);

                    }
                    else{
                        //console.log('invalid')
                    }
                }

            }

            Packet.prototype = {
              ip: this.ip,
              message: this.message
            };


            router = new Router(['WAN', 'LAN1', 'LAN2']);

                device1 = new Device('192.168.0.1');
                router.connect(device1, 'LAN1');

                device2 = new Device('192.168.0.10');
                router.connect(device2, 'LAN2');

                wan = new Device('62.88.120.10');
                router.connect(wan, 'WAN');
                wan.emit('data', new Packet('192.168.0.1', 'Hello '));
                wan.emit('data', new Packet('192.168.0.10', 'Hi,'));
                wan.emit('data', new Packet('192.168.0.10', ' guys'));
                wan.emit('data', new Packet('192.168.0.1', 'world!'));
                wan.emit('data', new Packet('192.168.0.1', 'shit!'));
                router.totalPackets();
                router.totalBytes();
                router.totalPackets('LAN1');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a mistake:

```
Device.prototype = {
    // ...
    packetdata: []
}
```

That creates a single array that will be assigned as the `packetdata` attribute every time a new `Device` is instantiated. So when you modify one `Device`'s `packetdata` (unless its `packetdata` attribute has been reassigned), you're modifying that one array, which affects every `Device`.

You can create a new `packetdata` array for each `Device` by creating it in the constructor.

```
function Device(ip) {
    this.ip = ip;
    this.packetdata = [];
}
```

Alternatively, you could stick with the original protoype, but treat the arrays as immutable values. So to add packet data to a device, instead of mutating the array

```
device.packetdata.push(message);
```

you could reassign it

```
device.packetdata = device.packetdata.concat(message);
```

But that would be a rather atypical design, since most javascript programmers don't think in terms of immutable data structures.